# terraform import app configuration key with colon in name

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I am trying to import existing application configuration keys into my state. I have run into issues with the key name having colons. The specific error message is:

> Cannot import non-existent remote object

I am using PowerShell to run my import, so I have had to do some escaping for the imported index.

maint.tf

```
resource "azurerm_app_configuration" "app-config" {
  location            = "centralus"
  name                = "MyAppConfig"
  resource_group_name = "MyResourceGroup"
  sku                 = "free"
}

module "app_config_key" {
  source = "./keys"

  providers = {
    azurerm = azurerm
  }

  for_each = local.vault_data

  key_name        = each.key
  store_id        = azurerm_app_configuration.app-config.id
  vault_id        = var.vault_id
  vault_reference = each.value.vault_key_name
}
```

locals.tf

```
locals {
  vault_data = {
    "ThirdParty:AbcCompany:Data1" = {vault_key_name = "AbcCompanyData1"},
    "ThirdParty:AbcCompany:Data2" = {vault_key_name = "AbcCompanyData2"},
  }
}
```

import statement

```
terraform.exe import module.app-configuration.module.app_config_key[\`"ThirdParty:AbcCompany:Data1\`"].azurerm_app_configuration_key.configuration_key /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourcegroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.AppConfiguration/configurationStores/MyAppConfig/AppConfigurationKey/ThirdParty:AbcCompany:Data1/Label/%00
```

What I have tried

```
terraform.exe import module.app-configuration.module.app_config_key[\`"ThirdParty:AbcCompany:Data1\`"].azurerm_app_configuration_key.configuration_key /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourcegroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.AppConfiguration/configurationStores/MyAppConfig/AppConfigurationKey/ThirdParty--AbcCompany--Data1/Label/%00

terraform.exe import module.app-configuration.module.app_config_key[\`"ThirdParty:AbcCompany:Data1\`"].azurerm_app_configuration_key.configuration_key /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourcegroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.AppConfiguration/configurationStores/MyAppConfig/AppConfigurationKey/`ThirdParty:AbcCompany:Data1`/Label/%00

terraform.exe import module.app-configuration.module.app_config_key[\`"ThirdParty:AbcCompany:Data1\`"].azurerm_app_configuration_key.configuration_key /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourcegroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.AppConfiguration/configurationStores/MyAppConfig/AppConfigurationKey/ThirdParty%58AbcCompany%58Data1/Label/%00
```

This import statement is based on the information found in [Terraform's documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_configuration_key#import)

Comment: I think it should be `terraform import 'module.app-configuration.module.app_config_key[\"ThirdParty:AbcCompany:Data1\"]' <the rest>`.

Comment: The issue is really about the second parameter. I have the first part working with the apostrophes. The same approach does not work for the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the same in my environment:

Code:

```
resource "azurerm_app_configuration" "appconf" {
  name                = "kavyasarappConf12"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
  name                       = "kavyasarabojukv"
  location                   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name        = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  tenant_id                  = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  sku_name                   = "premium"
  soft_delete_retention_days = 7

  access_policy {
   //  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

   key_permissions = [
    "Get", "List", "Update", "Create", "Import"
  ]

  secret_permissions = [
"Get", "List","Delete","Set",
  ]

  certificate_permissions = [
    "Get", "List", "Update", "Create", "Import" 
  ]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "kvs" {
  name         = "kvs"
  value        = "szechuan"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
}


resource "azurerm_app_configuration_key" "test" {
  configuration_store_id = azurerm_app_configuration.appconf.id
  key                    = "key1"
  type                   = "vault"
  label                  = "label1"
  vault_key_reference    = azurerm_key_vault_secret.kvs.versionless_id

}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "appconf_dataowner" {
  scope                = azurerm_app_configuration.appconf.id
  role_definition_name = "App Configuration Data Owner"
  principal_id         = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
}
```

Tried:

```
terraform import azurerm_app_configuration_key.test  /subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.AppConfiguration/configurationStores/kavyasarappConf12/AppConfigurationKey/key2/Label/%00
```

Received the same error:

[image]

Tried as suggested in the form by @marko e terraform import 'module.app-configuration.module.app_config_key["xxxx"]' <>

and could execute successfully

[image]

Sometimes the issue can also be because of using  wrong account in terraform.

Comment: This did not work for me because the second part parameter is the actual problem. The first parameter is fine.